# Highlight table view cell on click, not on release

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with a list of items. When I click on one of those items I want the background to be highlighted. I have that code working but the colour changes on release, not on the click itself. How can I highlight when the user taps on the cell and not when he/she releases it?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    Help_Cell *cell =(Help_Cell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

    v.backgroundColor=[self colorForHex:[appDel.appColorSettings objectForKey:@"cellColor2"]];

    cell.backgroundView=v;

    cell.title.textColor=[self colorForHex:[appDel.appColorSettings objectForKey:@"cellColor1"]];
}
```

I want it to happen like a button. Is there an `onClick` method for a UITableView or a UITableViewCell besides `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

**EDIT**

Here is my code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Help_Cell *cell =(Help_Cell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

    v.backgroundColor=[self colorForHex:[appDel.appColorSettings objectForKey:@"cellColor2"]];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView=v;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of creating cell, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, write below code:

```
UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
v.backgroundColor = [self colorForHex:[appDel.appColorSettings objectForKey:@"cellColor2"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```

No need to write anything in didSelectRow method.

Comment: I like that idea but adding that into my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not working. Would that be affected if I have another `UIView v` set to the background view?

Comment: You should add it for selectedBackgroundView. Not for backgroundView. It will not make any problem, if you have some other view as a backgroundView. Post some code also, so I can check.

Comment: In my edit I had a `cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` which would remove any selected style I was adding. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this as option

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

}
```